# How to set a constant from the command line when running rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

With some rails commands, it is possible to set a constant from the command line e.g.

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails server
```

I want to do something similar with rspec; I want to set a constant from the command line that can be used to change some tests, e.g.

```
TEST_COLOR=red rspec spec
```

and then in a test access the value of `TEST_COLOR`. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try to use that variable in your code with `ENV['TEST_COLOR']` and see. I mean, you can even write a one line script which makes use of environment variables and it works out of the box, I tried. So I'm reasonably confident this works even in rspec.

One suggestion: given that could be not clear to someone else that rspec needs that environment variable, maybe use `ENV.fetch('TEST_COLOR', 'default value')`, where 'default value' is a reasonable default, so that if anyone runs rspec without that variable, everything is fine anyway.

Comment: That works well without any changes, though I already use the dot_env gem. Would it work without the dot_env gem?

Comment: I'd say yes, but dotenv could be very useful anyway :)

Comment: @Obromios the dotenv gem populates `ENV` based on assignments in a `.env` file (hence the name), making it easier to have per-project environment settings.